# Tell if user has granted website permanent permission to get location in browser

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I am calling navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition with no troubles.  In my web app I have a more user friendly screen that explains the use of the user's location and they press a button to initiate this request.  This is all working lovely jubbly.

However, when a user says "always grant this permission" I want to be able to skip this whole process and just get the location automatically.  So, is there a way to do something like:

```
if (!navigator.geolocation.hasPermission)
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(etc, etc);
else
    showMyLovelyReasonsWhy();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have to make a workaround for this to happen.

Please see:
[Is there a way of detecting whether a user has already given permission to use navigator.geolocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537282/is-there-a-way-of-detecting-whether-a-user-has-already-given-permission-to-use-n)

Comment: Thanks Matto, yes this is the same issue and I had considered using a cookie for it.  Seems like a little hole in the spec.  Thanks for clearing it up though!

Comment: Although I've just realised - this solution will store if the permission was given but not distinguishable if the permanent permission is given.  So the next time the user visits the site I still cannot tell if they gave it in a permanent manner, so sadly this actually doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You will have to check using the `successCallback` every time. If it passes, the permission was given. You're right about this being a little odd. There should be an easier way :)

Comment: It just means I am stuck giving a bad user experience.  Either I force them to explicitly press each time, even for frequent visitors; or else request automatically on repeat visitors and (on iPhones it seems) fill their screen with the request.  They don't even have a check to permanently remember (iPhone 4S). Poobums.  Whine over.  Thanks Matto.